# Convert XML document stored as binary to XML?

Tags: marklogic

I saved a bunch of content in MarkLogic as binary format documents instead of XML. When I decode the document, it's XML.  The side-effect of this error is that my searches don't include those documents.

Is there a way to convert the format of a document in-situ?  If not, is there a way to do some kind of mass conversion?  Any other ideas on how I can resolve this?

I know how to list all the URIs for binary documents:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace qry  = "http://marklogic.com/cts/query";
let $binary-term :=
  xdmp:plan(/binary())//qry:term-query/qry:key/text()
let $binary_uris := cts:uris((), (), cts:term-query($binary-term))
return $binary_uris
```

and I know how to decode the documents:

```
xdmp:binary-decode(fn:doc($uri)/node(), "UTF-8")
```

but what I don't know is what to do after that.  I can loop over that list of `$binary_uris` and decode them, but how do I take that result and overwrite the existing document in a batch process?

Answer (score 4):

Depending upon how your docs were saved as `binary()` nodes, you might be able to used [`xdmp:quote()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:quote) and then [`xdmp:unquote()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:unquote).

Below is a quick proof of concept that shows how content that was saved as binary can be turned back into either text or XML:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
xdmp:document-insert("/test.xml", 
  binary{ xs:hexBinary(xs:base64Binary(xdmp:base64-encode(xdmp:quote(<doc>test</doc>))))}),
xdmp:document-insert("/test.txt", 
  binary{ xs:hexBinary(xs:base64Binary(xdmp:base64-encode(xdmp:quote("test" ))))})
;
for $ext in ("xml", "txt")
let $doc := doc("/test." || $ext)
where $doc/node() instance of binary() 
      (: you could also restrict to docs who's URIs end with .xml, .txt, etc :)
return
  let $doc-text := xdmp:quote($doc)
  let $doc-decoded :=
    if (fn:starts-with($doc-text, "&lt;")) 
    then xdmp:unquote($doc-text)
    else $doc-text 
  return
    $doc-decoded
;
xdmp:document-delete("/test.xml"),
xdmp:document-delete("/test.txt")
```

If you wanted to "fix" the documents, you could then use [`xdmp:node-replace()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:node-replace) to replace the `binary()` node with the decoded document:

```
xdmp:node-replace($doc/node(), $doc-decoded)
```

You could run a batch job, using the [MarkLogic Java DMSDK](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-movement-sdk/) or a [CORB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) job to select those docs and re-save them.

Comment: I've got the code for the first part (how to find the documents and how to decode them), but I hadn't thought about using the DMSDK and node-replace; thanks, that will help a bunch.